# UITableViewRowAction customise title font size in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, uitableviewrowaction

I have an edit and a delete tableViewRowAction in my tableViewCell. Currently I'm using the built in emojis to use as my title, but it is too small. How do I make the font larger?

I know we can only customise a limited amount of things in the tableViewRowAction. But is there a way to go around it to make just the title font bigger?

I checked other threads and most of them used:

```
UIButton.appearance().setAttributedTitle(NSAttributedString(string: "Your Button", attributes: attributes), forState: .Normal)
```

with a set attribute that determines the font size of course. However, this affects ALL buttons, and that isn't good.

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are setting this to `UIButton` so it is set for all UIButton objects.

You can set it for specific button object like,

```
  let myButton: UIButton = UIButton()  //your button here
  let attributedStr: NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString()
  myButton.setAttributedTitle(attributedStr, forState: .Normal)
```

**Update :**

You can set title as attributed string.

check [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewRowAction_class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UITableViewRowActionStyle)  for that and refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29049318/how-to-do-custom-font-and-color-in-uitableviewrowaction-without-storyboard) for more details

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. (: However, UITableViewRowAction is not of type UIButton. So I can't use the UIButton route to set the title size.

Comment: Thanks!  I understand but how do I set title which is of type String to a NSAttributedString? It gives me an error. Here is my code: `let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20)] as Dictionary!
        
        let attributedStringRemove = NSAttributedString(string: "✖︎", attributes: attributes)` and then adding attributed string into title here: `let removeAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: attributedStringRemove)`

Comment: You're welcome!! Yes, that means you have to used default font size then.  If you are not allowed to set attributed text then you can't change title implicitly. I suggest you to use `delete` or `remove` kind of text instead of `x` so that it shows some bigger effect.