# Change color of UITableViewRowAction title text

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

I want change the color of UITableViewRowAction title. I want the “Download” to be written in red.

[image]

This is the code for the button -

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {


        let downloadButton = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Download") { action, index in

            var url: String

            if self.searchController.active {
                url = String(self.filteredPapers[indexPath.row].url)
            } else {
                url = String(self.papers[indexPath.row].url)
            }

            url = url.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "%20")
            print(url)
            let destination = Alamofire.Request.suggestedDownloadDestination(directory: .DocumentDirectory, domain: .UserDomainMask)

            self.table.editing = false

            Alamofire.download(.GET, url, destination: destination).response { _, _, _, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Failed with error: \(error)")
                } else {
                    print("Downloaded file successfully")
                }
            }

        }

        downloadButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.79, green:0.79, blue:0.81, alpha:1.0)


        return [downloadButton]

    }
```

Comment: There's no (public) API for `UITableViewRowAction` to do that. I'd suggest using one of the many swipe frameworks (I currently use `SWTableViewCell`, but there are tons of options).

Comment: This answer, from the question @sschale mentioned, should work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36145706/5143847

Answer (score 0):

Since **UITableViewRowAction** is a type of **UIButton** we can change text colour by changing the *appearance of UIButton class*.add the following code in your `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath`

```
UIButton.appearance().setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: doesn't this change the color of every button in the application?

Comment: yes, it changes all UIButton

Comment: @Nathan, you change only the buttons inside your table view cell by UIButton.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [YourCustomUITableViewCell.self]).setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)