# Swift 3 own font for UITableViewCellActionButton

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

this is my first question here, so feel free to point out anything I might be doing wrong ;)

I'm currently trying to give the UITableViewRowAction-Buttons in my Application a custom font. For that I used [David Seeks Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43564194/8940633) and put in in an extension like this:

```
extension UITableViewCell{

override open func layoutSubviews() {

    super.layoutSubviews()

    for subview in self.subviews {

        for sub in subview.subviews {

            if String(describing: sub).range(of: "UITableViewCellActionButton") != nil {

                for view in sub.subviews {

                    if String(describing: view).range(of: "UIButtonLabel") != nil {

                        if let label = view as? UILabel {

                            label.font = UIFont(name: "CaptureSmallz", size: label.font.pointSize)

}}}}}}}}
```

It works, but it seems to cut the space of the overlying cell elements:
[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUoOZ.png)
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling `label.sizeToFit()`, that should resize things after you've changed the label's font size.

This seems like a good place for a subclass of the UITableViewCell though, to achieve all the customization that you're looking for.

Comment: thanks that worked. although its not enough to just call label.sizeToFit inside the extension. One needs to this inside the "cellForRowAt"-function for every label inside the cell. But the Indicator is still hidden. Do you know how I call something like sizeToFit for him, too?

Comment: I already tried "cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator" after the labels were resized but it didn't work.

Comment: I'd recommend putting all of this code within the 'cellForRow' (better yet: subclass), honestly. Try putting the `cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator` within the 'cellForRow' code.

Comment: I had it in the "cellForRowAt" right before returning the cell, but it didnt change anything. Also I just realized that the separator-lines are not visible in between filled cells.

Comment: The separators get visible after swiping left once to see the RowActionButtons, but the disclosure indicator never shows up.